# How 2nd derivative is determined? Question is from string theory (A string model).

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

[enter image description here][1]

This question is related to Mathematical modeling. I have many times to get second derivative but failed to drive. I would remain thankful for resolving my issue.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4sA5.jpg

Comment: This is *not* [string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory).

Comment: @J.G. Well, I mean I guess it's literally **string** theory haha

Comment: Please edit in your attempt to compute $\tfrac{D^2u}{Dt^2}$ from (2.2.1).

Comment: I am thankful, I am new to this platform but I would be greatly thankful If somebody helps me to bring few of the steps of second derivative.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Such an underrated comment.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Thanks for your overrated support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{D^2u}{Dt^2}&=\frac{D}{Dt}\left(\frac{Du}{Dt}\right) \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+V\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+V\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \\
&=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+V\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t \partial x}+V\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t}
+V^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \\
&=u_{tt}+V_tu_x+2Vu_{xt}+V^2u_{xx}
\end{align*}

Comment: Accept my heartiest thanks.